# Оптимальный и безопасный способ доступа извне к приватному std::string с гарантией readonly

Tags: c++

Мне, как человеку избалованному Qt implicit sharing, хочется понять как грамотно действовать в следующей ситуации в стандартном C++. Имеется класс, содержащий приватную переменную (например std::string) с большим объемом данных. Необходимо иметь к ней доступ без копирования, с гарантией того, что хитровыделанный пользователь класса не поменяет ее извне. Пример:

```
using namespace std;
class A
{
public:
    // data - большой текстовый массив
    A(string* data) : _data(data) {}
    // копирование (медленно)
    string data_1() const { return *_data; }
    // const_cast позволит залезть в _data
    const string* data_2() const { return _data; }
private:
    string* _data;
};
```

Как обычно поступают в таком случае?

Comment: Используйте `std::string_view`. Он содержит только константный указатель на строку.

Comment: "...с гарантией того, что хитровыделанный пользователь класса не поменяет ее извне" - такой гарантии быть не может никак.

Comment: @MrBin - спасибо, это то что надо! С другой строны проблема решается только конкретно для std::string, но не в общем случае.

Comment: @AnT - механизм implicit sharing такую гарантию дает. Конечно там есть некий оверхед при подсчете количества ссылок на разделяемую память и копирование указателей, но он не превышает аналогичного оверхеда например у shared_ptr по сравнению с обычными указателями.

Comment: Почему бы просто не вернуть константную ссылку?

Comment: @gbg Хочется гарантии, что объект не будет "хакнут" через const_cast.

Comment: "*избалованному Qt implicit sharing*" - странное заявление, ведь вроде как эта особенность является одним из бичей qt от которой постоянно отгребают несчатные разработчики. "*не будет "хакнут" через const_cast*" - ни один из qt классов от этого не защищает. А в данном случае стоит отказаться от использования сырых указателей и 1) выделять сразу объект `string _data;` 2) возвращать ссылку на него `string const & data_2() const { return _data; }`

Comment: @VTT честно говоря, имея здоровенный проект на Qt и реализуя практически все свои классы, требующие активного копирования, через QSharedData, ни разу не имел с этим проблем. За что и от кого они огребают?

Comment: `QSharedData` сам по себе не подразумевает implicit sharing. Хотя постоянное использование Shared указателей также может быть проблемой (это и к shared_ptr относится). Про проблемы с implicit sharing вроде как много написано, в том числе и в офф документации. Если, имея "здоровенный проект", с ними сталкиваться не приходилось, то однозначно имеет место [ошибка выжившего](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Систематическая_ошибка_выжившего). Попросите квалифицированных коллег провести ревью вашего кода Свежий опытный глаз наверняка сразу выявит пачку проблем, потом будете удивляться, как оно работало

Comment: @nrw2000 - так это полумеры, возьмут адрес вашего класса, сделают ему reinterpret_cast  и поправят все что нужно по смещению. Если программист что-то там "хакает" таким образом - он ССЗБ

Comment: Не поменяет случайно - константность. Не поменяет злонамеренно - помнится, у Саттера была целая куча задач, как сделать нечто неразрешенное - и все это можно было делать... Запретить в принципе - ну, разве что поместить в *физически* read-only память - типа, на CD :) Можно попробовать предоставлять наружу копию данных, но вы прямо пишете - без копирования...

Comment: @VTT "Попросите квалифицированных коллег провести ревью вашего кода Свежий опытный глаз наверняка сразу выявит пачку проблем, потом будете удивляться, как оно работало" - да кто только не смотрел. Либо все неквалифицированные, либо не знаю что и сказать. Вот типичный пример реального кода: https://pastebin.com/KXsexr1A

Comment: @nrw2000: Никакой механизм не может давать такой гарантии. Защитить данные от модификации "хитровыделанным пользователем" можно только через предварительное *копирование* данных. Но вас, согласно сказанному вами, это не устраивает. Если нет копирования, т.е. пользователь получает доступ к оригинальным данным, то "хитровыделанным пользователь" всегда сможет их модифицировать.

Answer (score 0):

Такой вариант Вам удобен?

```
using namespace std;
class A
{
public:
   // используем std::move для "тяжелого объекта"
   explicit A(std::string data) : _data(std::move(data)) {}
   // ничего не копируем
   const std::string& data() const noexcept { return _data; }
private:
   // тоже const, все равно инициализируем строку в конструкторе
   const std::string _data;
};
```

Comment: Спасибо, я уже понял что ничего кроме выставления наружу константного указателя или ссылки, использовать все равно не получится. Кстати разве в этом варианте не будет копирования "тяжелого объекта" во временный объект при передаче в конструктор класса A строки, лежащей в переменной?

Comment: @nrw2000, смотря что Вы туда будете передавать, т.е. да, такой вариант имеет место быть.